# Configuration of two Entites with EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the two following Entitites with the corresponding EntityTypeConfigurations

```
public class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ClientNo { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class MasterConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Master>
{
    public MasterConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Master", "MySchema");
        HasKey(k => k.Id);
        HasMany(m => m.Childs)...
       // Connect Master.RequestId to Child.RequestId 
       //     and Master.ClientNo  to Child.ClientNo
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ClientNo { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}

public class ChildConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Child", "MySchema");
        HasKey(k => k.Id);
    }
}
```

I would like to configure it that way that when I do

```
myAppContext.Masters.Include(m => m.Childs).First(m => m.Id == 4);
```

It would load all the Master with ID 4 and the Corresponding maching Childs.
Somehow I can't make it work.

Comment: Can there be many *Masters* according to one `RequestId`?

Comment: @AdilMammadov yes it can.

Comment: And I suppose that, `ClientNo` is related with `RequestId`, am I correct?

Comment: Yes @AdilMammadov

Comment: Actually there's one Request that can hold many Masters than can hold  many Childs. The DB is wrongly designed and Child should have a FK MasterId, but i will not be able to change that for some legacy reasons. @AdilMammadov

Comment: Oh, you should have mentioned that before. Now my answer below is not valid

Comment: oops sorry @AdilMammadov. But basically you're saying that what i want is not possible right? I will mark your answer as correct then. thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible or not. But I do not know any way of making it  work and I do not believe that it is possible. But, you should wait a bit, in case someone as solution to suit your needs. If you don't receive answer, then I will be happy if you accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships are based on *FK* to *PK*. In your scenario `RequestId` is not primary key either of `Master` or `Child`. You should have `Request` model, which has `RequsetId` as *PK* and should have navigation properties to `Master`, and `Child` model should not directly bound to `Request`, it should bound to `Master`. Your models should look like this:

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Master> MasterCollection { get; set; }
}

public class RequestMap  : EntityTypeConfiguration<Request>
{
    HasKey(m => m.Id);
}

public class Master
{
    // Id is same as RequestId
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class MasterConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Master>
{
    public MasterConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Master", "MySchema");
        HasKey(k => k.Id);

        // Map Request and Master
        HasRequired(m => m.Request)
            .WithMany(m => m.MasterCollection)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.RequestId);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
    public int MasterId { get; set; }

    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
}

public class ChildConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Child", "MySchema");
        HasKey(k => k.Id);

        HasRequired(m => m.Master)
            .WithMany(m => m.Childs)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.MasterId);
    }
}
```

By changing your models to suit this, now you can load your `Master` and related  `Childs` as you want to:

```
Master master = myAppContext.Masters
    .Include(m => m.Childs)
    .First(m => m.Id == 4);
```

If you want to load `Request` data according to Master then:

```
Master master = myAppContext.Masters
    .Include(m => m.Request)
    .Include(m => m.Childs)
    .First(m => m.Id == 4);
```

You can also load `Master` and `Request` details for any child:

```
Child child = myAppContext.Childs
    .Include(m => m.Master.Request)
    .First(m => m.Id == 2);
```